# How to create a submit and close button in an overlay

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a button that will submit and then close an overlay window.

The code for my button is:

```
<a href="javascript:additem('Info to add here', 10.00,1);" role="button"><button class="purchase btn btn-warning">Select</button></a>
```

What am I missing to get the button to close after the selection has been made?

Comment: Needs a lot more context... We have no clue how any of it is coded. What is the mystery overlay? How would you normally close the overlay? Why don't you combine them?

Comment: I cannot combine due to multiple buttons on the overlay.

Comment: Code still remains unclear. You are not going to get an answer.

Comment: Try this https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear about your question. It's from assumption. Maybe it can help.

```
function closeSelf(){
// do something

if(condition satisfied){
   alert("conditions satisfied, submiting the form.");
   document.forms['certform'].submit();
   window.close();
}else{
   alert("conditions not satisfied, returning to form");    
} }


<input type="button" class="purchase btn btn-warning" value="Select"  onclick="closeSelf();"/>
```